# How to use post and get values in VB.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I recently took over a web based project that is written vb.net (written by someone that did not know vb.net before he started).

The current project used webforms and onclick triggers to get form values. It never posts any html form data.

Here is a base example to show what I need to know:

**login.aspx**

```
<form name="LoginForm" action="auth.aspx?ref=LoginForm" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="password" name="passphrase" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

**auth.aspx.vb**

```
Dim ref as String = ???
Dim username As String = ???
Dim passphrase As String = ???

Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT usrId FROM Users WHERE UserName =@ParamName AND Password =@ParamPass"

dbCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, dbConn)
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username)
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParamPass", passphrase)
dr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader
```

How assign these post and get values to these variables?

Comment: When not using serverside controls `(runat="server")`, you'll have to rely on Request.Form and Request.Querystring

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Could you please copy the example and show how you use Request.Form / Request.Querystring in the example and paste it as an answer? That way I can mark it as correct and upvote if need be. Thanks.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen why would you want to use runat="server" instead of submitting a form? Do people hate html built in functionality?

Comment: runat="server" is at the core of how asp.net webforms function. It allows you to access the controls server side; therein includes getting data and setting data. When not using that functionality you're left with standard HTML/ASP form functionality aka Request.Form

Comment: @Nightwolf runat="server" also submit the form. anytime you go to the server you'll submit a post (or a get).

Comment: @the_lotus are you saying that the submit button needs a runat="server" then you get a object / array with the form values you can utilize? If so please paste as an answer because that might be the better result.

Comment: @the_lotus I sometimes need to have the form dynamically add input fields that needs to be processed. If you can provide that with runat="server" then I will use this to an alternative to html form submit.

Comment: @Nightwolf yes, if the button has a runat="server" and you handle the onclick, then the value of the textbox (that is runat server) will be in an object. I would suggest you read beginner tutorial on asp.net, that's usually one of the first thing they teach. But using request will also work, just a different way of doing it.

Comment: @the_lotus Currently the project is written like that... it seems you and Allan are saying that is how it supposed to be. Look at https://www.travelstart.co.za/ ; Then select multi city and there you will see a button add another flight. This functionality was requested from me. This is piece of cake in html (and PHP); how would you handle additional fields with runat="server"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your problem I would think this would work:

```
Dim ref as String = Request.Querystring("ref") 
Dim username As String =Request.Form("username")
Dim passphrase As String = =Request.Form("passphrase")
```

As mentioned in my comment, if not using the asp.net webform functionality, you'll have to rely on the (basically) ASP version of functionality.
Check here for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_form.asp